# 16-puzzle: confusion over the number of inversions

Tags: permutations, puzzle

For one of my homework questions we were given a 16-puzzle and we had to find out if it is solvable; and then solve it. My 16-puzzle is

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
1&2&3&4\\\hline
5&6& &11\\\hline
10&9&7&8\\\hline
13&14&15&12 \\\hline
\end{array}

Now, I know all about parity of permutations and all that. I find the number of inversions. That'll be

$$
0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 0 + 0 + 1 + 1 + 1 +0 = 12
$$

Even. So this 16-puzzle can be solved. My confusion comes from when I slide my 7 tile upwards creating
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
1&2&3&4\\\hline
5&6&7&11\\\hline
10&9& &8\\\hline
13&14&15&12\\\hline
\end{array}

Now if I check the number of inversions I get

$$
0+0+0+0+0+0+0+3+2+1+0+1+1+1+0=9
$$

Which is odd. That shouldn't be possible though. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: I count just five transpositions for the first square: four for the 5-cycle (blank,12,8,11,7) and one for (9,10). That's an _odd_ permutation, but since the taxicab distance of the blank from the lower right is 3, and 5 + 3 = 8 is even, the puzzle is solvable. How do you get all the numbers in your sum? You should have gotten an odd sum, but your sum is even, which implies there is a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle#Solvability), you forgot to add the taxicab distance of the empty square from the lower right corner to the parity of the permuation. It's not suprising that the permutation changes parity when you apply a transposition, as a transposition has negative parity. You also forgot to add the number of inversions for the empty square (fictitiously labeled $16$); it just so happens that your move doesn't change the parity of that number.

Comment: Thank you so much! To clarify I need to add the taxicab distance of the empty square AND add the number of inversions of the empty square?

Won't the number of inversions for the empty square (square 16) always be 0?

Comment: @SammyAranny: The answer to the first question is yes. I don't see why the number of inversions for $16$ should always be zero. The way you counted the inversions, if I understand correctly, you noted for each number how many lower numbers come after it (in reading order). Since all other numbers are lower than $16$, the number of inversions for the $16$ would be the number of tiles that come after it, no?